# How to use python-social-auth with google only?

Tags: django, google-authentication, python-social-auth, django-1.6

I'm trying to add google authentication to my project

I installed it:

```
pip install python-social-auth
```

and added it in settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'##

SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'default': 'social.apps.django_app.default.south_migrations'
    }

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'myproject.middleware.AuthenticationCMSBackend',##
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY  = '507847...m.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'SEt-6...0j3'"""

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS =  (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)
```

As for the SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY and secert, I went to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and created them using localhost url (for testing for now)

I call it in template like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}"> login </a>
```

But I get this error:

> **Backend not found**

What am i doing wrong?

next step, I want to make sure only users I validate can authenticate not anyone with google account, how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In your setting.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 # Google
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
 # Django
 #'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
# Google Keys
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'KEY' # Client ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'SECRET_' # Client secret

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

context processors

```
'context_processors': [
                ...
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url('social/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
...
]
```

in your template add.

```
<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Entrar con la cuenta de Google</a></p>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing as I posted!  what is the difference? what should I correct?

Comment: where can i find `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY`? in google api console I have `Client ID` , `Client secret`,`Creation date` but I don't have `auth key`? @erajuan @cinoch